# Java swing ubuntu app does not load sqlite

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, ubuntu

I made a java swing application in Windows that uses sqlite database . I moved my application on Ubunty Linux ,downloaded the newest jdk and jre . When I run my application from Netbeans everything is fine , but when I run it from the dist folder ( right clicking on jar folder and choosing to be run with jre7) application starts but the data from sqlite database is not loaded . First I thought that this is about giving permissions inside Ubunty on my sqlite database for data to be read and written (right click in sqlite database folder and click Access option set to read and write and set , and enabling the file to be run as a program) .
What am I to do to enable my sqlite database to be loaded outside Netbeans Ide .

Comment: Show your error message

Comment: There is no error message , now I tried to run my app from console and it works ok but when I run in by mouse click it does not load sqlite database , this is an Ubunty stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Show your error message – AlexR 14 mins ago 
>          There is no error message , now I tried to run my app from console and it works ok but when I run in by mouse click it does not
>   load sqlite database , this is an Ubunty stuff. – Jovo Krneta 11 mins
>   ago

OK, this explains something.

When you are clicking jar file you are running application using command line like:

`java -jar yourjar.jar`

JVM opens your `MANIFEST.MF`, determins the main class and classpath and runs your application. I believe that in your case the classpath is not recognized correctly.

Here is the document that explains how to define it:
https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/jdev_including_a_classpath_in

> Class-Path
>
> The Class-Path tag is useful for specifying the list of the libraries
>   application needs to successfully run. You can specify the class path
>   like any other but use the blank character (' ') as the path
>   separator. Ie. no colon (':')or semicolon (';') as for the Un*x/Linux
>   or Win environments, respectively. To specify the Class-Path tag in
>   your MANIFEST.MF you need to include a line like the following:
>   Class-Path: lib/ojdbc14.jar lib/log4j.jar

I believe that since you created your exacutable jar on windows using IDE your classpath there is defined using windows specific separator `;`. Check this fact and if this is correct replace it by platform independent space character `" "`.

For example if your class path is defined as `Class-Path: one.jar;two.jar` replace it to `Class-Path: one.jar two.jar`

If however this is not the case check anyway the path. Is it a chance that path to driver jar is invalid for ubuntu? Do you probably use back slash or absolute path?

Check all these things. I believe that you will find problem quickly. 99% is that your problem is in class path.

Comment: I recreated my jar in Ubunty by importing the project in Netbeans again(this was the case from the begining)  .My application runs ok when I run it from Ubuntu console now(did not try it running from console before only from NetBeans in Ubuntu ,which was ok and by double clicking the jar in dist folder , that is right clicking it where it fails to load sqlite...), but again when I double click the jar file it does  not load the sqlite database, this is something about Ubunty!?